# Have you used all your daily rep yet?

Tags: discussion

Please remember to [vote early and vote often](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/)!

On day one I used all mine. Please remember to vote up good questions and good answers!

Comment: I second that! The more active we are in the beta, the better the site will be when it launches!

Comment: And remember, your vote limit for homebrewing doesn't carry over to meta, so be active on meta too!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I used all of mine today :)